# Getting data from my Database Handler to a Text View in my Activity

Tags: android, sqlite

New to Android Studio so some help would go a long way!

Trying to do a search where the user inputs an email and if its in the database, then it shows up in a text view.

I think my select is correct but here's the method in my Database Handler class:

```
public String searchEmail(String email)
    {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();


        String fName;
        String sName;
        String selectQuery = "SELECT FIRSTNAME, SURNAME FROM friends_table WHERE EMAIL=? ";
        Cursor c = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, new String[] { email });
        if (c.moveToFirst()) {
            fName = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("FIRSTNAME"));
            sName = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("SURNAME"));
        }
        c.close();

        return email;
    }
```

Then my search:

```
public void searchFriend(View v) {
        EditText emailSearch = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.emailSearch);

        String emailSearchString = emailSearch.getText().toString();
        myDB.searchEmail(emailSearchString);

    //I need to get the first name and surname from the db handler class
        TextView firstName = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.firstname);
        TextView surname = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.surname);

        firstName.setText("");
        surname.setText("");




    }
```

I'm just finding to difficult to understand how I'll show the first name and surname if the email matches.

Thanks guys, I love you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a new class User (with getters, setters) and try this:

```
public User searchEmail(String email) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

    User u = null;
    String selectQuery = "SELECT FIRSTNAME, SURNAME FROM friends_table WHERE EMAIL=? ";
    Cursor c = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, new String[] { email });
    if (c.moveToFirst()) {
        u = new User();
        u.setfName(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("FIRSTNAME")));
        u.setsName(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("SURNAME")));
    }
    c.close();

    return u;
}
```

Display results in activity:

```
public void searchFriend(View v) {
    EditText emailSearch = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.emailSearch);
    TextView firstName = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.firstname);
    TextView surname = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.surname);

    String emailSearchString = emailSearch.getText().toString();
    User user = myDB.searchEmail(emailSearchString);

    firstName.setText(user.getfName());
    surname.setText(user.getsName());

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a new class **User** and try this:

```
public User searchEmail(String email)
    {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

        User u = null;
        String selectQuery = "SELECT FIRSTNAME, SURNAME FROM friends_table WHERE EMAIL=? ";
        Cursor c = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, new String[] { email });
        if (c.moveToFirst()) {
            u = new User();
            u.setfName(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("FIRSTNAME")));
            u.setsName(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("SURNAME")));
        }
        c.close();

        return u;
    }
```

Comment: Okay, but how can I can I get that to display the search results on a text view in a different activity